# Find the index of a character in a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have a string `NSString *Original=@"88) 12-sep-2012";` or `Original=@"8) blablabla";`

I want to print only the characters before the ")" so how to find the index of the character ")". or how could i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please accept the answer if you have solved your issue

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To print the characters before the first right paren, you can do this:

```
NSString *str = [[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@")"] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", str);

// If you need the character index:
NSUInteger index = str.length;
```

Answer (score 10):

U can find index of the character ")" like this:

```
NSString *Original=@"88) 12-sep-2012";
NSRange range = [Original rangeOfString:@")"];
if(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
 NSString *result = [Original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, range.location)];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to see the characters before **")"**

```
   // this would split the string into values which would be stored in an array
   NSArray *splitStringArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
   // this would display the characters before the character ")"
   NSLog(@"%@", [splitStringArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSUInteger index = [Original rangeOfString:@")"];

NSString *result = [Original substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, index)];
```

Answer (score 3):

try the below code to get the index of a particular character in a string:-

```
NSString *string = @"88) 12-sep-2012";
NSCharacterSet *charSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@")"];
NSRange range = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:charSet];

if (range.location == NSNotFound) 
{
    // ... oops
}
else {
    NSLog(@"---%d", range.location);
    // range.location is the index of character )
}
```

and to get the string before the ) character use this:-

```
NSString *str = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@")"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another soluation:

```
NSString *Original=@"88) 12-sep-2012";
NSRange range = [Original rangeOfString:@")"];
NSString *result = Original;

if (range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    result = [Original substringToIndex:range.location];
}

NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
```